# AWS Lambda Postgres DB Connection issue on time intervals

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
Please see below the error that I am getting while executing a lambda after 
a particular time interval. Any suggestions will be appreciated.
```

> "pid": 1,
>       "level": 50,
>       "err": {
>           "message": "Connection terminated unexpectedly",
>           "name": "SequelizeConnectionError",
>           "stack": "SequelizeConnectionError: Connection terminated unexpectedly\n
>       at connection.connect.err 
>       (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection- 
>       manager.js:132:20)\n    at Connection.con.once 
>       (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:211:11)\n    at Object.onceWrapper 
>       (events.js:313:30)\n    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)\n    at 
>       Connection.emit (events.js:208:7)\n    at Socket.
>       (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:130:10)\n    at emitNone 
>       (events.js:111:20)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)\n    at 
>       endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)\n    at _combinedTickCallback 
>       (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)\n    at process._tickDomainCallback 
>       (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)"
>       },
>       "msg": "Connection terminated unexpectedly"

```
The DB connection code is as below

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, 
process.env.DB_PWD, {
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
dialect: 'postgres',
logging: process.env.DB_SHOW_LOGS === 'true',
port: process.env.DB_PORT,
pool: {
 max: 5,
 min: 1,
 acquire: 30000,
idle: 10000
},
operatorsAliases: false
});
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What do you expect?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**